# How do I move into a next line when using code.interact?

Tags: python

I come from ruby, where you can use `binding.pry` and do `next` to go to the next line or `step` to go inside a method.
Is there an equivalent for python? I have found this code snippet:

```
import code; code.interact(local=dict(globals(), **locals()))
```

It works well to inspect the line where you place it, but I want to be able to observe how the code is executed line by line and inspect it as it goes.
Is there a way to instruct it to go to the next line from the interactive console?
I'd also like to have something like `whereami` to tell me which line am I at, since sometimes I place many `code.interact` and I don't know which one I'm at.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a debugger, not `code.interact`. (Also, `code.inspect` does not exist.)

Comment: Thank you, I changed the title

Answer (score 0):

[pdb](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pdb.html) is Python's debugger with many of the functions you are seeking. [Python 3.7 includes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#breakpoint) `breakpoint()` which drops you into the debugger from wherever you called it without even having to import `pdb`

Edit: Just noticed the title change. You will want to use the `banner` parameter in `code.interact` as well as `exitmsg` added in 3.6. You can make multiple points in your code and give each one a name so you know exactly where you are in your code.

For example:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    code.interact(banner="in for loop", local=locals(), exitmsg="out of for loop")
    print(i)
```

will produce something like

```
in for loop
>>> ^Z

out of for loop
0
in for loop
>>> ^Z

out of for loop
1
in for loop
>>> ^Z

out of for loop
2
in for loop
>>> ^Z

out of for loop
3
in for loop
>>> ^Z

out of for loop
4
```

depending on what you decide to do.